# MouseEvent on Label breaks when you click the text

Tags: java, javafx, label, mouseevent

So I am trying to make a javafx version of the 15-puzzle, where you slide the little square and try to put them in order.  I have an array of Labels, and the goal of my code is that when you click on a label, it swaps its text with an adjacent label, if that label is empty.  So I have:

```
void moveTile(MouseEvent event){
    Label clicked = (Label)event.getTarget();
    int position = Arrays.asList(labels).indexOf(clicked);
    if(position > 0 && labels[position-1].getText().equals("")){
        String temp = clicked.getText();
        clicked.setText(labels[position-1].getText());
        labels[position-1].setText(temp);
    }else if(position < 15 && labels[position+1].getText().equals("")){
        String temp = clicked.getText();
        clicked.setText(labels[position+1].getText());
        labels[position+1].setText(temp);
    }else if(position>3 && labels[position-4].getText().equals("")){
        String temp = clicked.getText();
        clicked.setText(labels[position-4].getText());
        labels[position-4].setText(temp);
    }else if(position < 12 && labels[position+4].getText().equals("")){
        String temp = clicked.getText();
        clicked.setText(labels[position+4].getText());
        labels[position+4].setText(temp);
    }
}//
```

It works fine, but only if you don't click on the text.  IF you click directly on the text part of the label it throws: javafx.controls@9.0.4/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.LabeledText cannot be cast to javafx.controls@9.0.4/javafx.scene.control.Label

I assume what is happening is that when it looks for the event target, it is getting the text rather than the label itself.
Is there a way to work around this?  The problem specifies that you must use labels, so I can't just use buttons.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/sedj601/GameOfFifteen) is something you can look at for ideas.

Comment: How are you adding the `EventHandler`? If you add a unique `EventHandler` to each `Label` then the `Object` returned by `MouseEvent.getSource()` will be the `Label`. **Edit**: Actually, you can probably get away with exactly whatever you're doing and simply change `event.getTarget()` to `event.getSource()` _provided the `EventHandler` was added to the `Label`s and only them_.

Comment: That worked. Thanks!